# "There is no default printer selected" error when Windows default printer is not set up

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder, printers, network-printers

I need to open the Printer Dialog box when there is no Windows default printer setup. It works fine with the below code when a Windows default printer is set up.

```
TPrintDialog *dlgPrint = new TPrintDialog(frmDisplayDetail);
if( dlgPrint->Execute()) { //code here }
```

But if there is no default printer setup in Windows, `dlgPrint->Execute()` throws an exception:

> There is no default printer selected

To check the default printer index, I used `Printer()->PrinterIndex`. This value becomes inaccessible when there is no Windows printer setup:

> error E2122 Function call terminated by unhandled exception XXX at address XXX

Am I doing something wrong? Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Too broad. Please post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception "There is no default printer currently selected" is thrown only by the `TPrinter::SetToDefaultPrinter()` method, when either:

- the Win32 API [`EnumPrinters()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692.aspx) function fails with an `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` error code when enumerating with the (undocumented) `PRINTER_ENUM_DEFAULT` flag.
- the `TPrinter::Printers` list does not contain the default printer.  If `EnumPrinters()` above does not report a default device, the default is then queried from the Win32 API [`GetDefaultPrinter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144876.aspx) function (Delphi/C++Builder 2009 and later), or the `device` value of the `[windows]` section of `%windir%\win.ini` (Delphi/C++Builder 2007 and earlier).

`TPrinter::SetToDefaultPrinter()` is called only by:

- the `TPrinter::PrinterIndex` getter if the `FPrinterIndex` member is currently -1.
- the `TPrinter::PrinterIndex` setter if the `FPrinterIndex` member is currently -1, or the property is being set to -1.

`TPrintDialog::Execute()` (which uses the Win32 API [`PrintDlg()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646940.aspx) function) first calls `TPrinter::GetPrinter()` to get a handle to the `DEVMODE` of the currently selected printer, which it then uses to initialize the dialog (via the [`PRINTDLG::hDevMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646843.aspx) field).  `TPrinter::GetPrinter()` reads the `TPrinter::PrinterIndex` property, so if there is no currently selected printer and no default printer, the exception is thrown.

If there is no default printer configured, you are basically out of luck, as you can't even set the `TPrinter::PrinterIndex` property to a value >= 0 since it will first call `SetToDefaultPrinter()` before checking if the new value matches the current value.

`TPrinter` has a long history of failing/crashing when there is no default printer configured in Windows.  To work around this, you should call the Win32 API `PrintDlg()` function directly instead.  At least then, you can manually call `TPrinter::GetPrinter()` (to get the initial `DEVMODE`) and wrap it in a `try/catch` block to discard any exceptions that it may throw.

If the dialog result indicates success, you can manually call `TPrinter::SetPrinter()` to assign the selected printer options to `TPrinter` for subsequent printing.

Answer (score 0):

I am checking existence of printers before the dialog usage:

```
// check printer interface
TPrinter *prn = Printer(); 
int pxs,pys,i=0;
if (prn==NULL)i=1;
if (prn->Printers==NULL) i=1;
if (prn->Printers->Count<=0) i=1;
if (i) return;
// use dialog
dlg_print->Options.Clear();
dlg_print->Options<<poPrintToFile;
if (!dlg_print->Execute()) return;
// print
prn = Printer();
pxs=prn->PageWidth;
pys=prn->PageHeight;
prn->BeginDoc();
for (i=0;i<dlg_print->Copies;i++)
    {
    if (i) prn->NewPage();
    // here render page into prn->Canvas as image in resolution pxs,pys
    }
prn->EndDoc();
```

where `dlg_print` is my dialog placed on the form.

Comment: I am checking for the printer before opening the dialog. In above code, dlg_print->Execute() will return an exception "There is no default printer selected" when there is no windows default printer selected. That's what the issue i mentioned.

Comment: @Santhosh just a silly question but did you check if `dlgPrint` is not null (since you create it dynamicaly)? where exactly it is in the code (I hope not in form constructor)?

Comment: Yes, i checked. It's not null. If the Printer()->PrinterIndex property properly setup with index, dlg->Execute() works fine. I am checking Printer classes in PASCAL code

Comment: @Santhosh in what event? it should be done only if your App/Forms are valid and running so after the initial resize and activate ... before some of the VCL stuff does not exist yet ...

Comment: The problem is that `TPrintDialog::Execute()` internally reads the `TPrinter::PrinterIndex` property, and that throws an exception if there is no default printer configured in Windows. See my answer for more details.